# Which events are called when delete product from cart?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, event-observer

If we click on Add to cart, we can call event `checkout_cart_product_add_after` , in same way , in cart page, there is **delete button** to remove Products from cart. what event we need to use onclick that "**Delete**" button.

I saw [this](https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-9/) , but i didt got exact event.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what you want to do, try one of these:

- `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_delete`
- `controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_cart_delete`
- `checkout_cart_save_before`
- `checkout_cart_save_after`
- `sales_quote_remove_item`
- `sales_quote_item_delete_before`
- `sales_quote_item_delete_after`